# Importing binlog as an sql file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, binlog

I created an sql file from a binlog using this command:

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2024-02-22 00:00:00" --stop-datetime="2024-02-23 15:55:00" /var/lib/mysql/binlog.000096 > ./mysql-backup/binlog_96_data.sql
```

but when I tried to import the sql file in my I got this error:

```
mysql -uroot -p hp_temp_db < ./mysql-backup/binlog_96_data.sql

ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 46: Duplicate entry '5891044' for key 'visit_diagnosis.PRIMARY'
```

I even tried to use the --force flag, I could see the logs on the terminal,and when it seemed like all my 176 tables were populated, they were empty when I checked them:

```
mysql -uroot -p hp_temp_db --force < /mysql-backup/binlog_96_data.sql
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 46: Duplicate entry '5891044' for key 'visit_diagnosis.PRIMARY'
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 104: Duplicate entry '11543738' for key 'visit_prescriptions.PRIMARY'
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 133: Duplicate entry '1591433' for key 'medicine_inventory.PRIMARY'
```

how can I work around the duplicate entry issue and get my tables to populated with data?

Comment: What would you like to do with the duplicate keys?